# What's the difference between a hash and hash reference in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, language-features, hash-reference

I would like to properly understand hashes in Perl. I've had to use Perl intermittently for quite some time and mostly whenever I need to do it, it's mostly related to text processing.

And everytime, I have to deal with hashes, it gets messed up. I find the syntax very cryptic for hashes

A good explanation of hashes and hash references, their differences, when they are required etc. would be much appreciated.

Comment: _*hands you an apple*_ pretend that's a hash.  _*hands you written directions to an apple in the fridge*_ that's a hash reference.

Comment: You might check out _Learning Perl_'s chapter on hashes.

Comment: @~quack: I wish that had been an answer rather than a comment so that I could upvote you properly.

Comment: @Dave: thanks, i appreciate it.  i left it as a comment 'cause the question asked for syntax examples and such, and i was too lazy to compete with gbacon's answer.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

A simple hash is close to an array. Their initializations even look similar. First the array:

```
@last_name = (
  "Ward",   "Cleaver",
  "Fred",   "Flintstone",
  "Archie", "Bunker"
);
```

Now let's represent the same information with a hash (aka associative array):

```
%last_name = (
  "Ward",   "Cleaver",
  "Fred",   "Flintstone",
  "Archie", "Bunker"
);
```

Although they have the same name, the array `@last_name` and the hash `%last_name` are completely independent.

With the array, if we want to know Archie's last name, we have to perform a linear search:

```
my $lname;
for (my $i = 0; $i < @last_name; $i += 2) {
  $lname = $last_name[$i+1] if $last_name[$i] eq "Archie";
}
print "Archie $lname\n";
```

With the hash, it's much more direct syntactically:

```
print "Archie $last_name{Archie}\n";
```

Say we want to represent information with only slightly richer structure:

- Cleaver (last name)

  - Ward  (first name)
  - June  (spouse's first name)
- Flintstone

  - Fred
  - Wilma
- Bunker

  - Archie
  - Edith

Before references came along, flat key-value hashes were about the best we could do, but references allow

```
my %personal_info = (
    "Cleaver", {
        "FIRST",  "Ward",
        "SPOUSE", "June",
    },
    "Flintstone", {
        "FIRST",  "Fred",
        "SPOUSE", "Wilma",
    },
    "Bunker", {
        "FIRST",  "Archie",
        "SPOUSE", "Edith",
    },
);
```

Internally, the keys and values of `%personal_info` are all scalars, but the values are a special kind of scalar: hash references, created with `{}`. The references allow us to simulate "multi-dimensional" hashes. For example, we can get to Wilma via

```
$personal_info{Flintstone}->{SPOUSE}
```

Note that Perl allows us to omit arrows between subscripts, so the above is equivalent to

```
$personal_info{Flintstone}{SPOUSE}
```

That's a lot of typing if you want to know more about Fred, so you might grab a reference as sort of a cursor:

```
$fred = $personal_info{Flintstone};
print "Fred's wife is $fred->{SPOUSE}\n";
```

Because `$fred` in the snippet above is a hashref, the arrow is necessary. If you leave it out but wisely enabled `use strict` to help you catch these sorts of errors, the compiler will complain:

```
Global symbol "%fred" requires explicit package name at ...
```

Perl references are similar to pointers in C and C++, but they can never be null. Pointers in C and C++ require dereferencing and so do references in Perl.

C and C++ function parameters have pass-by-value semantics: they're just copies, so modifications don't get back to the caller. If you want to see the changes, you have to pass a pointer. You can get this effect with references in Perl:

```
sub add_barney {
    my($personal_info) = @_;

    $personal_info->{Rubble} = {
        FIRST  => "Barney",
        SPOUSE => "Betty",
    };
}

add_barney \%personal_info;
```

Without the backslash, `add_barney` would have gotten a copy that's thrown away as soon as the sub returns.

Note also the use of the "fat comma" (`=>`) above. It autoquotes the string on its left and makes hash initializations less syntactically noisy.

Comment: Dropping by 7 years later to note that C and C++ allow pass-by-reference without use of a pointer. `void f(DataType & arg)` passes `arg` by reference, and does not require dereferencing to access or modify.

Comment: @JimV  That's when you pass a _reference_, declared with `&`, which is a 'sort of' an alias. The semantics _is_ pass-by-value.

Comment: A great post :). A comment -- perhaps a warning note would be worthy that `@_` aliases arguments, so one _can_ change them from the sub (except for hash keys)?

Comment: Once more example. These are three equivalents:

 `perl -e 'my %h = ( a => { b => { c => 123 } } ); print $h{a}{b}{c}'`  VS  `perl -e 'my $r = { a => { b => { c => 123 } } }; print $r->{a}{b}{c}'`  VS  `perl -e 'my $r = { a => { b => { c => 123 } } }; print $r->{a}->{b}->{c}'`

Answer (score 16):

The following demonstrates how you can use a hash and a hash reference:

```
my %hash = (
    toy    => 'aeroplane',
    colour => 'blue',
);
print "I have an ", $hash{toy}, " which is coloured ", $hash{colour}, "\n";

my $hashref = \%hash;
print "I have an ", $hashref->{toy}, " which is coloured ", $hashref->{colour}, "\n";
```

Also see [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Comment: Personally, I found it confusing to see the term `%hash` to describe a hash. It might be a good idea to relabel your `%hash` as `%favorite` just to drive the point home. The print statement would then be something like `print "My favorite toy is the $favorite{toy}";`

Answer (score 10):

> A hash is a basic data type in Perl.
>   It uses keys to access its contents.
>
> A hash ref is an abbreviation to a
>   reference to a hash. References are
>   scalars, that is simple values. It is
>   a scalar value that contains
>   essentially, a pointer to the actual
>   hash itself.

Link: [difference between hash and hash ref in perl - Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=380384)

A difference is also in the syntax for deleting. Like C, perl works like this for Hashes:

```
delete $hash{$key};
```

and for Hash References

```
delete $hash_ref->{$key};
```

The [Perl Hash Howto](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~abatko/computers/programming/perl/howto/hash/) is a great resource to understand Hashes versus Hash with Hash References

There is also another link [here that has more information on perl and references](http://www.antipope.org/charlie/attic/perl/hashes.html).

Answer (score 7):

See [perldoc perlreftut](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlreftut) which is also accessible on your own computer's command line.

> A reference is a scalar value that refers to an entire array or an entire hash (or to just about anything else). Names are one kind of reference that you're already familiar with. Think of the President of the United States: a messy, inconvenient bag of blood and bones. But to talk about him, or to represent him in a computer program, all you need is the easy, convenient scalar string "Barack Obama".
>
> References in Perl are like names for arrays and hashes. They're Perl's private, internal names, so you can be sure they're unambiguous. Unlike "Barack Obama", a reference only refers to one thing, and you always know what it refers to. If you have a reference to an array, you can recover the entire array from it. If you have a reference to a hash, you can recover the entire hash. But the reference is still an easy, compact scalar value.

Comment: @mjp66 The essential part of the answer is to use `perldoc perlreftut` which is installed alongside `perl` on the OP's computer. That is always the most accurate document for the *specific version of perl* the OP is using. The link is only included as a courtesy. So, in that sense, Perl documentation URLs are just like references. The content at the link may change, but the link will always point to the "Perl References Tutorial". Not all links are created equal. FYI.