# concept of hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between a hash and hash reference in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817394/whats-the-difference-between-a-hash-and-hash-reference-in-perl)

Hi,

Trying to understand the concept of hashes in perl 
The sample code is given below :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my %hash =();
%hash = ();
my $hash_ref = {};
$hash_ref->{dhg} = 'jhfkjd';
print $hash_ref->{dhg} . "\n";
$hash{abc} = 'def';
$hash{key2} = 0;
print "$hash{abc}\n";
```

I get the output as:

```
jhfkjd
def
```

I wanted to know what is the difference between $hash_ref and %hash that I have used,
although I know it syntactically.

I am absolutely new to perl. 
Any help will be valuable .

Thanks & Regards,
Tazim.

Comment: The line `%hash = ();` is redundant given the previous line (adorned with an additional `my`).