# Curly braces for a hash

Tags: perl

Which structure is created as following in Perl?

```
my $self = { Name => $name, Color => $class->default_color };
```

If it is a hash, then is the official notation not the following ( parentheses, `%` instead of `$`):

```
my %self = ( Name => $name, Color => $class->default_color );
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817394/whats-the-difference-between-a-hash-and-hash-reference-in-perl

Comment: I take it you're reading [Intermediate Perl](http://www.intermediateperl.com). :)

Comment: Just for reference, the `{}` are usually referred to `"curly"` braces.  "angle" ones are "<>"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data in `{ ... }` is a hash ref.

The data in `( ... )` is a list, but the context makes it into a hash.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's still a hash - but an anonymous one. And its reference is assigned to `$self`. [The doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References) says:

> A reference to an anonymous hash can be created using curly brackets:

```
$hashref = {    
  'Adam'  => 'Eve',     
  'Clyde' => 'Bonnie',
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Perl doesn't have a literal representation of a hash, so we create a hash as a list of key-value pairs. The anonymous hash constructor or assignment to named hash converts the list of key-value pairs to a hash.

The top line creates a hash reference which you assign to a scalar variable:

```
my $self = { Name => $name, Color => $class->default_color };
```

The bottom line assigns a list to a named hash:

```
my %self = ( Name => $name, Color => $class->default_color );
```