# How to print hash of hash in where one hash is reference to other

Tags: perl

I am trying to learn complex data structure in perl, for that i i have written a code but i am not getting any output :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

my %abc=(Education => "BE",Marital_Status => "Single", Age => "28", Working_Exp => "4yrs");
my %cde=(Education => "BE",Marital_Status => "Single", Age => "29", Working_Exp => "5yrs");


my %info =(info_one => "\%abc", info_two => "\%cde");

foreach my $val (keys %info)
{
  foreach my $check ( keys %{$info{val}})
  {
    print ${$info{val}}{check}."\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Use anonymous hashes that will help you to store and manage data.

Comment: @NaghaveerRGowda: you mean, use "[hashrefs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817394/whats-the-difference-between-a-hash-and-hash-reference-in-perl)", and you want to be more precise than saying "will help you to store and manage data" :)

Comment: @DanDascalescu: yes Its "hashrefs" and Thanks Dan :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For learning complex data structures in Perl, there's no better reference than the [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

The assignments to `info_one` and `info_two are` strings, so you want to remove the double quotes from around `\%abc` and `\%cde`. Also, you need to add the `$` scalar sign to `val` and `check` in the last `print` line, because those are variables.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

my %abc= (
    Education => "BE",
    Marital_Status => "Single", 
    Age => "28", 
    Working_Exp => "4yrs"
);
my %cde= (
    Education => "BE",
    Marital_Status => "Single", 
    Age => "29", 
    Working_Exp => "5yrs"
);


my %info = (
   info_one => \%abc,
   info_two => \%cde
);

foreach my $val (keys %info) {
    foreach my $check ( keys %{$info{$val}} ) {
        print ${$info{$val}}{$check}."\n";
    }
}
```

The last line is a little ugly, but as you read through the Data Structures Cookbook, you'll learn to use the `->` operator and write the statement more elegantly.