# Data::Dumper wraps second word's output

Tags: perl, data-dumper

I'm experiencing a rather odd problem while using Data::Dumper to try and check on my importing of a large list of data into a hash.

My Data looks like this in another file.

```
##Product ID => Market for product
ABC => Euro
XYZ => USA
PQR => India
```

Then in my script, I'm trying to read in my list of data into a hash like so:

```
open(CONFIG_DAT_H, "<", $config_data);       
while(my $line = <CONFIG_DAT_H>) {
    if($line !~ /^\#/) {
        chomp($line);
        my @words = split(/\s*\=\>\s/, $line);
        %product_names->{$words[0]} = $words[1];
    }
}
close(CONFIG_DAT_H);
print Dumper (%product_names);
```

My parsing is working for the most part that I can find all of my data in the hash, but when I print it using the Data::Dumper it doesn't print it properly.  This is my output.

```
$VAR1 = 'ABC';
';AR2 = 'Euro
$VAR3 = 'XYZ';
';AR4 = 'USA
$VAR5 = 'PQR';
';AR6 = 'India
```

Does anybody know why the Dumper is printing the '; characters over the first two letters on my second column of data?

Comment: Looks like carriage returns (`\r`) in the input. `chomp` won't get rid of them, try something stronger like `$line =~ s/\s+$//` instead

Comment: You need to pass a reference, `Dumper(\%product_names)`, and not use `%h->{key}` syntax (but `%h{key}`) -- OR -- if `*product_names` is in fact a hashref then you need to use the correct sigil, `$product_names->{key}` and `Dumper($product_names)`.

Comment: Looks like that regex worked.  Just to make sure I understand it, it is trimming any type of whitespace: \n, \r, \t, etc...  from the end of the line?  I didn't know that chomp() didn't kill other types of whitespace.

Comment: Also try setting `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;`.

Comment: `chomp` trims whatever [`$/`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR) is set to, typically `\n` on POSIXy systems.

Comment: @mob, It's `"\n"` on all systems (unless you assign something else to it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one unclear thing in the code: is `*product_names` a hash or a hashref?

- If it is a hash, you should use `%product_names{key}` syntax, not `%product_names->{key}`, and need to pass a reference to  [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html), so `Dumper(\%product_names)`.
- If it is a hashref then it should be labelled with a correct sigil, so `$product_names->{key}` and `Dumper($product_names}`.

As noted by [mob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168657/mob) if your input has anything other than `\n` it need be cleaned up more explicitly, say with `s/\s*$//` per comment.  See the answer by [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami).

I'd also like to add, the loop can be simplified by loosing the `if` branch

```
open my $config_dat_h, "<", $config_data  or die "Can't open $config_data: $!";

while (my $line = <$config_dat_h>) 
{
    next if $line =~ /^\#/;  # or /^\s*\#/ to account for possible spaces

    # ...
}
```

I have changed to the lexical filehandle, the recommended practice with many advantages.  I have also added a check for `open`, which should always be in place.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I know how to answer if it is a hashref or a hash.  What is the big difference between the two?  The way I've been treating it, is to associate the first column "product ID" with my second column "market".  

The big difference I saw between using dumper to print the hash versus using its reference, is the format change from print every piece of data to printing them in a proper list.

Comment: @JonBot  Those are different data structures.  If this is all your code, then you can decide whether you want it to be a hashref or a hash -- and then use it consistently.  A "hashref" is a _reference_ to a hash, it's a scalar that must start with `$`.  When you use it you _dereference_ it, so `$h->{key}`,etc. A hash starts with `%`. You access it directly, `$h{key}`. See [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for starters. As it stands now the code is incorrect.

Comment: @JonBot  Both of these allow you to use the key-value association. One better thing about a hashref is that it is a scalar, a single value, so much better for passing around to functions and such.  It's like a pointer in C. But then a bit more syntax is needed to use it.  One better thing about a hash is that you use the data structure directly, it's easier conceptually, and on the eyes (and hands).  And then there's a bit more of course :)

Comment: I did some research on the difference between the two, and I found a pretty good article on SO here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817394/whats-the-difference-between-a-hash-and-hash-reference-in-perl).  I believe I want to make use of a real hash not a hashref.  Thanks @zdim.

Comment: @JonBot Oh, that looks like a good one! (Didn't get to read it right now.)  Good if you know which you want!  I'd suggest that you do get informed and practiced with references -- one can't really do serious work without them.

Comment: @JonBot  I updated the answer with two more coding recommendations, which slipped by at first.  Also -- I looked through the post you link, it is excellent. Note though that `@_` aliases arguments, so if they are changed _directly_ (like `$_[0] = 1` in  a sub) the caller's variables _change_.   We don't want to do that of course, just a warning. A notable exception is keys in a hash, they cannot be changed from the sub.

Answer (score 1):

Humm... this appears wrong to me, even you're using Perl6:

```
%product_names->{$words[0]} = $words[1];
```

I don't know Perl6 very well, but in Perl5 the reference should be like bellow considering that %product_names exists and is declared:

```
$product_names{...} = ... ;
```

If you could expose the full code, I can help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The file uses CR LF as line endings. This would become evident by adding the following to your code:

```
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
```

You could convert the file to use unix line endings (seeing as you are on a unix system). This can be achieved using the `dos2unix` utility.

```
dos2unix config.dat
```

Alternatively, replace

```
chomp($line);
```

with the more flexible

```
$line =~ s/\s+\z//;
```

---

- Note: `%product_names->{$words[0]}` makes no sense. It happens to do what you want in old versions of Perl, but it rightfully throws an error in newer versions. `$product_names{$words[0]}` is the proper syntax for accessing the value of an element of a hash.
- Tip: You should be using `print Dumper(\%product_names);` instead of `print Dumper(%product_names);`.
- Tip: You might also find `local $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;` useful. Data::Dumper has such bad defaults :(
- Tip: Using `split(/\s*=>\s*/, $line, 2)` instead of `split(/\s*=>\s*/, $line)` would permit the value to contain `=>`.
- Tip: You shouldn't use global variable without reason. Use `open(my $CONFIG_DAT_H, ...)` instead of `open(CONFIG_DAT_H, ...)`, and replace other instances of `CONFIG_DAT_H` with `$CONFIG_DAT_H`.
- Tip: Using `next if $line =~ /^#/;` would avoid a lot of indenting.